# Process memory, GPU shared memory and x86 process on x64 windows address space

Tags: windows, visual-c++, memory-management, gpu, directx-11

Out of curiosity and some strange behavior observation.
How is the address space for x86 process presented when allocating both for the process itself using win32 memory management functions (`malloc/new afterall` go down there) and allocating textures on integrated intel GPU which uses machine's shared memory? Is the GPU allocations are part of process address space? Since I've seen today strange stuff happening to my process. I'm using x86 process on x64 machine, my process committed memory size is about ~1.3Gb, the GPU shared memory consumption is ~600Mb and I start to get `ENOMEM` from `HeapAlloc` when trying to allocate 32Mb buffer. I dont believe fragmentation is something to deal with here since the process runs up to minute. So I got the impression that the GPU memory is counted in the process address space, otherwise I cant explain how come the `HeapAlloc` returns null for CRT heap. Side note, DLL linked without /LARGEADDRESSAWARE, so 2Gb looks as the sum of above numbers (1.3+0.6)

Am I right? Wrong? Can anyone explain how it works?

EDIT001: A little clarification, the GPU consumes ~600Gb not out of the blue, but since I allocate textures using DirectX.

EDIT002: Test added
I skipped device initialization here
constexpr size_t dim = 5000;
    CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDescriptor(DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT, dim, dim, 1, 1, D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL);

```
std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> procData;
std::vector<CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>> gpuData;

// Some device/context init here

for(;;)
{
    {
        CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> tex;
        hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&texDescriptor, nullptr, &tex);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            gpuData.emplace_back(tex);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to create " << gpuData.size() << "th texture." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    {
        try
        {
            std::vector<uint8_t> buff(dim * dim, 0);
            procData.emplace_back(buff);
        }
        catch(std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to create " << procData.size() << "th buffer." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Just to remind, it is x86 process, with no LARGEADRESSAWARE setting, so, 2Gb available to it.
The above code produces 35 buffers and 34 textures. If you comment out the texture creating block, 70 buffers created. Well...

Comment: I'm not an expert in GPU, but virtual memory mapping for any specified process can be easily visualized by [VMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx). I suggest you to play with this tool and to print addresses of buffers you are curious about, so you can determine, what section them belong to.

Comment: Already did it... there is nothing special at first look, go figure

Answer (score 0):

no. "process address space" in windows means memory pages allocated for task.to deal with video memory you'll need ddk stuff.just "app" cant do  things of this kind and doesnt own anything "video".

Comment: Clarification added to the question

Comment: RAM is cutted by video card at hardware level.It doesnt have a clue about your process

Comment: Sure? maybe at driver level? otherwise OS will be not aware of memory 'stolen' from it...

Comment: after that card can deal with this memory without help of CPU.

Comment: @Алексей, link to any article confirming this statement would be really appreciated

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx